# Getting value of next row while iterating through rows

Tags: c#

myClass structure :

```
public class myClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalData { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ActivityTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a list of the above class List all ordered by ActivityTime say 'acts'.

I wish to convert my data to a list of following class..

```
public class newClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalData { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Here StartTime will have the same value as the prev class's ActivityTime and so I do not have a problem.
But EndTime should have the ActivityTime value of next list object, this I'm unable to figure how to get..
The last list object's EndTime can be same as starttime

so my code is ..

```
List<newClass> items = new List<newClass>();
foreach (var item in acts)
{

            newClass si = new newClass
                        {
                            Name=item.Name,
                AdditionalData=item.AdditionalData,
                StartTime = item.ActivityTime ,
                EndTime = //what do I do here??????

                        };
                        items.Add(si);

}
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Comment: Don't use foreach, use for loop, then you can use the index or index+1

Comment: If you inject instance of `List` to be available for every item, then `EndTime` can be a property which find `this` index in the list and return next item `StartTime`. Another option is to use kind of linked list data structure. Those two options allow you do not specify `EndTime` at all (if this is not clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a much elegant solution than for-loop:

```
        List<newClass> output = acts.Select((a, index) => new newClass()
        {
            Name = a.Name,
            AdditionalData = a.AdditionalData,
            StartTime = a.ActivityTime,
            EndTime = (index + 1 < acts.Count) ? acts[index + 1].ActivityTime : default(DateTime)
        }).ToList();
```

Or you can use a for loop instead of foreach:

```
List<newClass> items = new List<newClass>();
// assuming length > 0
int length = (acts.Length  % 2 == 0) ? acts.Length : acts.Length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < acts.Length; i++)
{
    newClass si = new newClass
    {
        Name=acts[i].Name,
        AdditionalData=acts[i].AdditionalData,
        StartTime = acts[i].ActivityTime ,
        EndTime = acts[i+1].ActivityTime
    };
    items.Add(si);  
}

if (length < acts.Length)
  // handle the last element as you wish
```

Comment: Update: `EndTime = acts[i+1].ActivityTime`

Comment: @Think2ceCode1ce: Thx. I updated it. (i forgot it when copy pasting.)

Comment: You should add `items` declaration as well for completeness.

Comment: @Think2ceCode1ce: i added it.

Comment: I think the OP still wanted the same number of items, so no need to skip half of them with `i += 2`.

Comment: @juharr: ok. i changed it.

Comment: how will I handle the last row, will it not throw an error if it does not find the row when I do acts[i+1].ActivityTime

Comment: @Arnab: look at my linq solution, if you dont like the for.solution. i edited the answer

Comment: @Arnab: To answer your question, this is the reason why i check in the beginning if the length is an even number.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to access the next iterator value until moving to that position.

What you can do here is to remember the previous item and update it in the next loop. Assuming that for the last element it should be empty it will look like this:

```
List<newClass> items = new List<newClass>();
newClass last = null;
foreach (var item in acts) {
        // update the last element here:
        if (last != null)
            last.EndTime = item.ActivityTime;
        newClass si = new newClass
                    {
                        Name=item.Name,
                        AdditionalData=item.AdditionalData,
                        StartTime = item.ActivityTime ,
                        //EndTime = null; // will be updated in the next loop
                    };
        last = si;
        items.Add(si);

}

// handle the last item (if needed):
if (last != null)
     last.EndTime = ... // special value for last item
```

Comment: how do I handle the EndTime for last item

Comment: @Arnab : Outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ you can create an extension method such as...

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> WithNext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var e = items.GetEnumerator();
        bool r = e.MoveNext();
        if (!r)
            yield break;
        do
        {
            T last = e.Current;
            var item = (r = e.MoveNext()) ? e.Current : default(T);
            yield return Tuple.Create(last, item);
        } while (r);
    }
}
```

... here is an example on how to use it ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = new int?[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var n in i.WithNext())
            //the last value will be paired with a null.  
            // you can use null coalesce to fill in the missing item.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", n.Item1, n.Item2 ?? 9);

        /*
            1 => 2
            2 => 3
            3 => 9
         */
    }
}
```